# Way to improve this multiple UNION query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find the users who have either

1. a shared video credit;
2. a shared production credit; or
3. a shared group.

This is currently the query I came up with:

```
SELECT profile_id FROM productions_productionmember WHERE production_id in 
    (SELECT production_id FROM productions_productionmember WHERE profile_id=?)
UNION
SELECT profile_id FROM groups_groupmember WHERE group_id in 
    (SELECT group_id FROM groups_groupmember WHERE profile_id=?)
UNION
SELECT profile_id FROM videos_videocredit WHERE video_id in 
    (SELECT video_id FROM videos_videocredit WHERE profile_id=?)
```

Relevant tables:

```
groups_groupmember
- profile_id
- group_id 

videos_videocredit
- profile_id
- video_id

productions_productionmember
- profile_id
- production_id
```

How can improve on this query?

Comment: IS there any master table for profiles? You can use outer join in that case for getting profile id meets any of the three criteria

Comment: do you encounter any problems with this query? (results only) except the performance

Comment: What is the first subselect for?

Comment: @juergend - to get all production_ids for which the given user is in (profile_id), and then select from that to get all other users (via profile_id) in that production -- it's the same logic for all three

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.profile_id 
FROM productions_productionmember p
left outer join groups_groupmember g on g.profile_id = p.profile_id
left outer join videos_videocredit v on v.profile_id = p.profile_id
WHERE v.video_id is not null or g.group_id is not null
or p.production_id in (SELECT production_id 
                     FROM productions_productionmember 
                     WHERE profile_id=?)
```

Comment: juergen - thanks for the answer. Out of curiosity, why do you use an outer join here instead of an inner join?

Comment: If you use an inner join you will shrink the result to profile_ids that are matching in groupsmember **and** videocredit. But you want either **or**.

Comment: In trying this query, I get a `Unknown column "g.production_id" in where clause.`

Comment: I am not sure if this query will give correct result? What happens if id is not in *productions_productionmember* but in any of other two tables. You have to go for full outer join in that case.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select *
From productions_productionmember as a,
     groups_groupmember           as b,
     videos_videocredit           as c
Where a.profile_id in (select ...) or
      b.group_id in (select ...) or 
      c.video_id in (select...)
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: This query returns an empty set.

Answer (score 0):

You need a list of profiles who are present in either of 3 tables.

```
     SELECT profile_id FROM productions_productionmember 
     UNION
     SELECT profile_id FROM groups_groupmember 
     UNION
     SELECT profile_id FROM videos_videocredit
```

If production_id\group_id\video_id can be null, than IS NOT NULL check can be used on these queries.

What is the profile_id that you are passing in you query? If you need to check if profile is present in any one of table, than you can put the where clause on the result returned by the above query.

```
     SELECT count(*) 
     from (SELECT profile_id FROM productions_productionmember 
           UNION
           SELECT profile_id FROM groups_groupmember 
           UNION
           SELECT profile_id FROM videos_videocredit ) subq
     where subq.profile_id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT pp.profile_id 
FROM productions_productionmember pp
JOIN productions_productionmember pp2 ON pp.production_id=pp2.production_id 
     AND pp2.profile_id=?
UNION
SELECT gg.profile_id
FROM groups_groupmember gg
JOIN groups_groupmember gg2 ON gg.group_id=pp2.group_id
     AND gg2.profile_id=?
UNION
SELECT vv.profile_id 
FROM videos_videocredit vv
JOIN videos_videocredit vv2 ON vv.video_id=vv2.video_id 
     AND vv2.profile_id=?
```

This eliminates inner queries. I can't tell you if this will increase query speed.
This query returns profile_ids which can be found two or more in the tables.